# Angular 2 Bootstrap Root Level Module

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Angular 2 [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) indicates that the root module need to be registered in the `imports` property of the root `NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When following the [Angular 2 Styleguide](https://angular.io/styleguide) would it it make more sense to register the NgbModule in the `shared` or `core` module? If so, how would one execute the `forRoot()` for this 3rd party module so that I can be used as part of the `SharedModule` being imported into other feature modules? Can it be registered as a provider in `CoreModule`, but would a singleton be a smart or even possible choice for a 3rd party library such as ng-bootstrap?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [
    FooComponent
  ],
  providers: [FooService],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    FooComponent,
    NgbModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

The question is, where should 3rd party modules go if they are going to be re-used throughout select feature components of the application with the goal of keeping the base application module "clean" through the use of CoreModule and SharedModule as demonstrated in the style guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Angular2 documentation, I would lean towards putting things like ng-bootstrap in SharedModule:

> SHAREDMODULE
>
> It may re-export other widget modules such as CommonModule,
>   FormsModule and **modules with the UI controls that you use most widely**.

**Source:** https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-module-recommendations

Here is an example Shared module that I use in one of my apps...stripped down for simplicity:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Third Party Modules
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot() // Required for bootstrap module
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Feature modules that import SharedModule can now use ngb features in their components.

Comment: It seems that calling forRoot() is not recommended by the NG team. From docs:
`Only call and import a .forRoot result in the root application module, AppModule. Importing it in any other module, particularly in a lazy-loaded module, is contrary to the intent and will likely produce a runtime error.` Source [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html]